# Linking libraries and header files g++

Tags: c++, dll, linker, g++, .lib

I have been referring to https://learnopengl.com/. In those tutorials, many libraries were used for performing different tasks. I have worked on those tutorials on Windows 7 in Visual Studio 2013, linking all the .lib files and .dll files correctly for that project inside Visual Studio 2013.

But now the issue is that I want to run the program from command line. But I can't run, since none of the libraries and header files are linked and I get various errors saying Couldn't locate *filename* and unresolved *name* in function.

Any ideas how do I link the libraries and header files so that I can run the program from command line?

I know this can be marked as an open ended and not clear question, but I am stuck and all the answers which I have gone through did not describe clearly about linking the .lib files?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to *build* the project from the command line? Use msbuild.

Comment: This is quite broad and comes down to learning how to build programs using `g++` on the command-line, including specifying include paths and linking in libraries. You can find all this information in the toolchain's manual and it is well-covered online.

Comment: The [code repository](https://learnopengl.com/Code-repository) comes with a CMakeLists.txt. Use that, be happy. If nothing else, use it to generate a Ninja build script and steal the commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Michael Chourdakis suggested, msbuild was the thing I was looking for.